# laravel use with() , pluck() together

Tags: php, laravel

[image: Query Output]

`\App\Post` :

```
function PostMeta(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\PostMeta');
}
```

And my Query : ( pluck is not working) -

> I need to use less database queries

```
$query = \App\Post
      ::with(array('PostMeta'=>function($query){
          $query->pluck('key','value');
      }));
       $query->get();
```

I need to get `title_en` , But I cant use pluck here!

## New Update

solved:

```
function get_PostMeta(){
      // print_r($this->relations['PostMeta']);
      return $this->relations['PostMeta'];
    }


$query = \App\Post::with('PostMeta')->get();
      foreach ($query as $key => $post){
        $post->meta = $post->get_PostMeta()->pluck('value', 'key');
      }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this while eager loading the data, but you can use collection method with the same name `pluck()` in the view when accessing the relation data:

```
{{ $post->postMeta->pluck('value', 'key') }}
```

In this case, you'll avoid N+1 problem and get data in the format you want.

**Update**

Since you want to prepare data for Vue, here's a small example of how you could iterate over the collection:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $post->meta = $post->postMeta->pluck('value', 'key');
    unset($post->postMeta);
}
```

Comment: @danialdezfooli you can iterate or use `map()` over a collection of posts to add new `Post` property and use `$post->postMeta->pluck('value', 'key')` to build `key => value` list for it.

Comment: @danialdezfooli please check update section of my answer if you need a small example.

Comment: thanks,it's solved but i have many queries ( for each post) here : (

Comment: @danialdezfooli I've just checked this for many-to-many relation and it creates just 2 queries as usually. Maybe some other code generate those queries?

Comment: each $post->postMeta->pluck  make one query (30post = 32 queries)

Comment: @danialdezfooli do you use `with()` to load `postMeta` before using `foreach()`? Inside `foreach()` do you use `postMeta()` or `postMeta`? If you're using `postMeta()` it will create a query instead of using loaded data.

Comment: please take a look at new Update

Comment: @danialdezfooli you're using `post_meta` instead of relation name which is `PostMeta`, that's the reason. Also, you're using the code which is different from what I've shown.

Comment: @danialdezfooli please read my previous comment. The problem is you're not using eager loaded data.

Comment: what do you recomend to use less queries :D :( - i dont know eager loading :(( ?

Comment: @danialdezfooli man, you're doing something wrong. I'm pretty sure you're using relation instead of loaded data. The correct code just can't create additional queries. Here's what my code does with my test data:  http://i66.tinypic.com/m8jmlj.png

Comment: thanks , solved - with only 2 query . the solved code are on update